# MicroService Architeture Decision

Tags: microservices

I have a requirement to act as a middleware service, which consumes data from external APIs, performs business logic, and sends the data to my frontend.

My initial design is to keep three independent services. All my requests will first reach the Gateway, which will then forward them to the Provider (which holding the business logic). If any external data is required, then the Provider will contact the Consumer and get the response.

The only disadvantage I observe here is the code duplication in the Provider and External services. What is the best way to design this?

[image]

```
Service A

@GetMapping("/users/{userId}")
fun getUser(@PathVariable userId: String): ResponseEntity<UserResponse> {
    val userResponse = userService.getUser(userId)
    return ResponseEntity<UserResponse>(userResponse, HttpStatus.OK)
}

Service
fun getUser(userId: String) : UserResponse {
    return try {
        clientService.getUser(userId)
        // Here my Business logic will come as part Provider 
    } catch (ex: FeignException) {
        throw FeignException
    }
}

FeignClient
 @GetMapping("/users/{userId}")
fun getUser(@PathVariable userId: String): UserResponse
```

Service B

```
@GetMapping("/users/{userId}")
fun getUser(@PathVariable userId: String): ResponseEntity<UserResponse> {
    val userResponse = userService.getUser(userId)
    return ResponseEntity<UserResponse>(userResponse, HttpStatus.OK)
}

Service
fun getUser(userId: String) : UserResponse {
    return try {
        clientService.getUser(userId)
    } catch (ex: FeignException) {
        throw FeignException
    }
}

FeignClient
 @GetMapping("http://external.com")
fun getUser(@PathVariable userId: String): UserResponse
```

Comment: What code duplication do you expect to have between `Provider` and `External`?

Comment: @GuruStron Here i added the sample code, If you observe the Service A (Provider) makes an External Call. 

The Responsiblity of External call is get the date from the external, and The 
Responsiblity of Provider service is to do business logic on top of that.

Here mostly the controller code, POJO class and exception class are duplicated..How can we avoid this with a better approach ?

Comment: I would argue that this is not that much of duplication to care about.